# How to change string value dynamically with string interpolation for a string loaded from json file

Tags: string, flutter, dart, sprint

I have 3 json files for translations. I want to translate this message:
"ERROR_MESSAGE": "Verification failed, %s tries left.".

I am using sprintf package, and when I load the string it doesn't change the value dynamically. The % sign shouldn't be escaped, so it would work in my opinion.

```
sprintf(loadedString, [remainingTries]);
```

Comment: Exactly what is `loadedString`?  What is the result of `sprintf`? (The code you've shown doesn't seem to do anything with the resulting string.) Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

You could either use:

```
sprintf(loadedString, [remainingTries.toString()]);
```

or change %s to %i.